# Date Format Issues SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have an application which imports a DAT file into some SQL Server tables.

The DAT file sometimes contains incorrect date formats.

Example:

```
DateCreated = 000100893
```

The `DateCreated` column in SQL Server is a `datetime` type.

The application fails when importing the data due to incorrect format and I have to manually null out these values so I can re-import.

Is there a way in SQL to have restrictions on the datetime column? For example, if the data is not in the correct format, automatically null out the column? I cannot change the `datetime` datatype for that column because most of the time the dates are correct and I am using this column for other calculations.

Comment: Why not parse the date?

Comment: This is standard ETL, Extraction, Transformation, and Load.  For the extraction, import your DAT file into a staging table where all the fields receiving data are varchar.  The transformation part is to update other columns from the varchar columns.  In this case, you would be updating dateCreated from dateCreatedVarchar, using a where clause to filter out values like 'fred' and 'barney'.  The load part is to write to your main tables from the staging table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`TRY_PARSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) function:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE(DateCreated AS datetime)
```

It returns `null` if `DateCreated` can't be cast into `datetime`

Answer (score 0):

According to [TRY_CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx), you can do :

```
 SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime2, '000100893') AS Result;
```